# Python Tkinter stopwatch not working on frame

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to build a user interface for my reaction game. I have set up frames on top of each other but when I add my stopwatch feature onto one of the frames the start button doesn't work. I have tested the reset button and the quit button and they work fine. I can't test the pause button as the stopwatch doesn't start. Can anyone help me?

Here is the code for the frame and stopwatch:

```
class LvlOneR(tk.Frame):
 def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.controller = controller
    label = tk.Label(self, text="Level One",
                     background='white',
                     foreground='dodger blue',
                     font=TITLE_FONT)
    label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
    #stopwatch 
    def update_timeText():
        if (state):
            global timer
            # Every time this function is called,
            # we will increment 1 centisecond (1/100 of a second)
            timer[2] += 1
            # Every 100 centisecond is equal to 1 second
            if (timer[2] >= 100):
                timer[2] = 0
                timer[1] += 1
            # Every 60 seconds is equal to 1 min
            if (timer[1] >= 60):
                timer[0] += 1
                timer[1] = 0
            # We create our time string here
            timeString = pattern.format(timer[0], timer[1], timer[2])
            # Update the timeText Label box with the current time
            timeText.configure(text=timeString)
            # Call the update_timeText() function after 1 centisecond
        self.after(10, update_timeText)
    # To start game
    def start():
        global state
        state = True

    # To pause the game
    def pause():
        global state
        state = False

    # To reset the timer to 00:00:00
    def reset():
        global timer
        timer = [0, 0, 0]
        timeText.configure(text='00:00:00')

    # To leave game our program

    def leave():
        controller.show_frame("ReactionGame")

    # Simple status flag
    # False mean the timer is not running
    # True means the timer is running (counting)
    state = False 

    # Our time structure [min, sec, centsec]
    timer = [0, 0, 0]
    # The format is padding all the
    pattern = '{0:02d}:{1:02d}:{2:02d}'
    # Create a timeText Label (a text box)
    timeText = tk.Label(self, text="00:00:00",
                        background='white',
                        foreground='dodger blue',
                        font=("Helvetica", 150))

    startButton = tk.Button(self, text='Start', command=start)


    pauseButton = tk.Button(self, text='Pause', command=pause)

    resetButton = tk.Button(self, text='Reset', command=reset)

    quitButton = tk.Button(self, text='Quit', command=leave)

    timeText.pack()
    startButton.pack()
    pauseButton.pack()
    resetButton.pack()
    quitButton.pack()
    update_timeText()
```

Here is the code for the set up of the frames:

```
class Game(tk.Tk):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    # the container is where we'll stack a bunch of frames
    # on top of each other, then the one we want visible
    # will be raised above the others
    container = tk.Frame(self)
    container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)


    self.frames = {}
    for F in (LoginScreen, MainMenu, ReactionGame, MemoryGame, HighScores, LvlOneR):
        page_name = F.__name__
        frame = F(container, self)
        self.frames[page_name] = frame

        # put all of the pages in the same location;
        # the one on the top of the stacking order
        # will be the one that is visible.
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        frame.configure(background='white')

    self.show_frame("LoginScreen")

def show_frame(self, page_name):
    '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
    frame = self.frames[page_name]
    frame.tkraise()
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

I suppose (no offense intended) that you did not try to break down your code?

- Does the widget work for itself?
- When does the error start to appear? 
  (certain level of placing widgets inside others?)

That would be what debugging is about. breaking down your code into single elements and verify them one by one.

To me this looks  alot like "here is code, it does not work, why?"

I suppose it does nothing as you do nothing to start the timer functionality (at least the functions are all declared inside your init function - why?)

Or is it the indentation that mixed up the code?

**Edit 1**

Just recognized - you are having **circular dependencies** (parent controlling child AND child controlling parent) - try to avoid that and only do it if there is a real crucial reason to do so.

There are (98% of the cases I assume) ways to handle it different which has following pros:

- more readable
- easier to maintain
- a lot easier to debug

**Edit 2**

Where is `state` initialized?

Putting `state = False` above `class LvlOneR(tk.Frame):`
and `global state` right after `def update_timeText():`

solves at least one of your issues. your function will recognize the state variable.

Comment: Sorry first time using this.What code should I put up to make it easier to see? The stopwatch works fine on its own, just not when added to my created frames. I tried your edit 2 but it doesn't recognize the timer variable if i put global state after the update_timeText

Comment: Windows. I have sorted it out the problem. Thanks for your help anyway

Comment: If so, Please let the Community know what solved your issue. You can also answer your own question.